# Simple network monitoring tool for android devices connected to LAN

Tags: android, networking, wifi, monitoring

I'm currently trying to write code to monitor my LAN. The setup is as follows, I have two  access point one connected to my machine which is running both an XMPP and SIP server. I have built an Android client which can connect to the servers via wifi and provide the user with VOIP and IM within the local network.

I want to achieve the following.

- Monitor network bandwidth
- Switch android devices to another access point if the access point is being overloaded.

I have looked at Simple Network Management Protocol but have no idea how I would implement something like that. I'm new to coding in general and probably a bit out of my depth with this kind of project, but I really need to try get something working for this.

My intention is to write the code myself if possible. I'm not looking for a defined answer more of general approach on how I could achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably too broad for SO. And as for SNMP, do the devices support SNMP? I'd run a collection daemon on your machine and have it server a local website to monitor status. Easier to code/maintain/extend.

Comment: Thanks for the response and pointing me in the right direction. I think I can make this work using this https://collectd.org/